# Root router on Symfony not working without '/' on nginx

Tags: symfony, nginx, router

I have a simple root that is not working without /
So this http://example.com/app is trowing the error:

> ResourceNotFoundException  NotFoundHttpException HTTP 404 Not Found No
>   route found for "GET /app"

but if I do http://example.com/app**/** (I added the '/' at the end of the url) the router is working.

The router:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;


class IndexController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="index")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return $this->render('index/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'IndexController',
        ]);
    }
}
```

What I'm missing ? the problem is on the nginx configuration?

```
server {
  listen 80;

    server_name ~^(?<folder>[^.]*).magana.dev.example.fr;


    charset utf-8;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    set $symfonyRoot /var/www/projects/dev/magana/$folder/htdocs/app/public;
    set $symfonyScript index.php;

    root /var/www/projects/dev/magana/$folder/htdocs;
    access_log /var/www/projects/dev/magana/$folder/access.log;
    error_log  /var/www/projects/dev/commons/logs/magana_error.log;

    client_max_body_size 200M;

    location ~* .(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js|css)$ {
        access_log        off;
        log_not_found     off;
        expires           30d;
        add_header Pragma "public";
    }
    location /app {
        root $symfonyRoot;
        rewrite ^/app/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        try_files $uri @symfonyFront;
    }
    location @symfonyFront {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $symfonyRoot/$symfonyScript;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /app/$symfonyScript;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI /app$uri?$args;
    }


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {            
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV magana;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k; 
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $folder.magana.dev.example.fr;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to understand if you divide different blocks of location.

```
location = /app {
    return 301 /app/; # this will add a / at the end only if the url is /app
                      # without tailing slash, same host, same everything
}

location  /app/ {
    #do what you want to do now, because of the "= /app" rule,
    #you'll always have /app with a / at the end
}
```

Hope I helped.